# What does -I mean in the directory names?

Tags: directory

I wonder what does '-I' mean in front of the directory names like these

' -I/opt/local/include/opencv/ -I/opt/local/include/'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `-I` followed by a directory is a compiler flag that instructs the compiler to search the given directory for additional source code files.